# Changing php link on a logo to an external site

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

How do I change homepage link (/) to an external link to another site in this code?

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home" class="site-title site-logo-text" <?php echo esc_attr( $header_text_color ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="YOUR_OTHER_LINK_HERE" rel="home" class="site-title site-logo-text" <?php echo esc_attr( $header_text_color ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?></a>
```

Comment: still opens the hp

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed url for the external link, you don't have to put it inside

Just put it inside the href attribute like so  and that should do it

Comment: I have no idea how. It's a wp template and the link needs changing

Answer (score 0):

If you want that link to point to another (external) resource, then make it simple, remove the unnecessary PHP code and put the URI in the `href` attribute. As I put `HTTPS://EXAMPLE.COM/` below.

```
<a href="HTTPS://EXAMPLE.COM/" rel="home" class="site-title site-logo-text" <?php echo esc_attr( $header_text_color ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?></a>
```